# I cannot understand BFS Tree Edges in Algorithm Design Manual

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

I can't understand what this mean

> The graph edges that do not appear in the breadth-first search tree also
> have special properties. For undirected graphs, non-tree edges can point only
> to vertices on the same level as the parent vertex, or to vertices on the level
> directly below the parent. These properties follow easily from the fact that each
> path in the tree must be a shortest path in the graph. For a directed graph,
> a back-pointing edge (u, v) can exist whenever v lies closer to the root than u
> does.

I understand that 'The graph edges that do not appear in the breadth-first search tree also
have special properties.'. But how can I know the these property follow easily from the fact that each path in the tree must be a shortest path in graph? Also, for a directed graph, for a directed graph, how can I prove a back-pointing edge (u, v) can exist whenever v lies closer to the root than u does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we’re working with a BFS tree, all nodes in the same level of the tree must be at the same distance from the root node. So, for example, a node at depth five must have distance five from the root node. Similarly, a node at depth ten must have distance ten from the root.

First, let’s talk undirected graphs. Imagine there’s an edge {u, v} not in the BFS tree. Now, suppose u and v are more than two levels apart in the tree, and specifically that v is at least two levels below u. That means that the distance from the root node s to v is two more than the distance from s to u. Consequently, the length of the shortest path from s to v is at least two edges more than the length of the shortest path from s to u (that’s the definition of shortest paths). But that’s not true here: we can get a path from s to v that’s only one edge longer than the shortest path from s to u by following the shortest path from s to u, then following the edge {u, v}. Something’s gone wrong here, and specifically it was our assumption that v is two or more levels below u.

For directed graphs, you can indeed have directed edges that jump back up to higher levels in the tree. A very simple way to see this: consider a triangle of nodes u, v, w where u has an edge to v, v has an edge to w, and w has an edge to u. What does the BFS tree look like?

Comment: Wow Thanks for answers! I have one more question...
If BFS starts at [w], the BFS tree looks like [w] -> [u] -> [v] and back-pointing edge [v] points to [w]. So  edge (v, w) means jump back up to higher levels. And [u] is more close to root node [w] than [v]. But the back-pointing edge is (v, w). I can' understand... Sorry

Comment: Yep, that’s correct. And w is closer to the root than v because w is the root. :-)

Comment: I can understand now Thank :)